# Java Generics Issue (w/ Spring)

Tags: java, generics, spring

I think I may be a victim of type erasure but thought I'd check with others here first.

I have the requirement to do something like this:

```
public interface FooFactory {
   public <T extends Bar> Foo<T> createFoo( Class<T> clazz );
}
```

It is perfectly valid to write this code. However, I'm trying to implement this functionality using a Spring `BeanFactory` and I can't do it.

What I'd like to do is this...

```
public class FooFactoryImpl implements BeanFactoryAware {
   private BeanFactory beanFactory;

   public <T extends Bar> Foo<T> createFoo( Class<T> clazz ) {
      return beanFactory.getBean( ????????? );
   }

   public void setBeanFactory( BeanFactory beanFactory ) {
      this.beanFactory = beanFactory; 
   }
}
```

As you can see, I've put in ???????? where I'd like to retrieve a bean of type `Foo<T>`, where T extends Bar. However, it is not possible to derive a Class object of type `Foo<T>` and so I assume what I'm trying to do is impossible?

Anyone else see a way round this or an alternative way of implementing what I'm trying to do?

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: What's the `clazz` parameter for?

Comment: Why are you trying to use a bean factory? Surely you can use standard Spring configuration to achieve this?

Comment: @Rob people use bean factories sometimes to get finer control of lifetime than you can get by just controlling lazy, or to take advantage of a prototype to get multiple instances.

Comment: @Mar I think it clues the compiler in as to what T is, sort of, since there are no T objects or x<T> objects in the parameter list. But I could easily be foggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't define a beans of type `Foo<T>` with specialized `T` in Spring context, i guess that you actually have subclasses of `Foo<T>`:

```
abstract public class Foo<T> { ... }

public class FooString extends Foo<String> { ... }
public class FooInteger extends Foo<String> { ... }
```

-

```
<bean id = "fooInteger" class = "FooInteger" />
<bean id = "fooString" class = "FooString" />
```

In this case you can use the fact that type parameters are not erased from superclass definition:

```
public class FooFactory implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private Map<Class<?>, Foo<?>> beans = new HashMap<Class<?>, Foo<?>>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> Foo<T> createFoo(Class<T> c) {
        return (Foo<T>) beans.get(c);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx)
            throws BeansException {

        Collection<Foo> candidates = ctx.getBeansOfType(Foo.class).values();
        for (Foo candidate: candidates) {
            Type superclass = candidate.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
            if (superclass instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                ParameterizedType t = (ParameterizedType) superclass;
                Class<?> p = (Class<?>) t.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
                beans.put(p, candidate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had worked out something along these lines too. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is a type erasure situation. Since you can't get a `Class` for `Foo<T>`, you have to work with `Foo` and suppress the warning.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends Bar> Foo<T> createFoo( Class<T> clazz ) {
      return (Foo<T>) beanFactory.getBean("Name of Bean", Foo.class);
}
```

You might find [this file](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/common/common/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/helpers/CastUtils.java) interesting -- it's a utility class with warnings suppressed that Apache CXF uses to centralize all these unfortunate incidents.

Of course, all this assumes that your XML (or whatever) config will result in a usable `Foo`.

Comment: +1 for answering before I had a chance, one note though, the parameter clazz is not needed.

Comment: @And are you sure? I thought it was needed to tell javac what T is for the particular invocation, since there's no object of T or something<T> in the parameter list. I admit that I'm squishy on the topic, feel free to edit the answer if I'm confused.

Comment: Well if you do something like `Foo<Bar> var = fooFactoryImpl.createFoo()`, the compiler infers the time from the variable (in this case Bar). And if you want to use a specific type you could always call 
`fooFactoryImpl.<someTypeThatExtendsFoo>createFoo();` .

Comment: For example if you have `public <T> T method(Foo<T> foo) {//code}` and try to call it like `TypeThatExtendsBar t = method(fooFactoryImpl.<TypeThatExtendsBar>createFoo());` which won't work without the specific parameter - not giving the parameter implies the method returns Bar)

Comment: Thanks for the input, everyone. An interesting discussion for sure!